# createRecord for relationship of unsaved record

Tags: ember.js

I have the following scenario:

1- Parent route that creates a record for multi-page form

```
routes/feedback.js
model() {
  return this.get('store').createRecord('feedback');
},
```

2- child route that return two models, question is non-related model that return multiple questions showing in dynamic route. And answer which creates a record that answer these questions in its page

```
routes/feedback/question.js
model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      question: this.get('store').findRecord('question', params.question_id),
      answer: this.get('store').createRecord('answer')
    })

  },
```

3- Answer has a belongsTo relationship feedback

```
models/answer.js
choice: DS.attr(),   // receives data from question through a controller
feedback: DS.belongsTo()

models/feedback.js
submittedAt: DS.attr(),
answers: DS.hasMany()
```

4- data passed from a question to an answer record through controller

```
controllers/feedback/question.js
getChoice(choice) {
  let answer = this.get('model.answer');
  let questionId = this.get('model.question').get('id');

  answer.setProperties({
    choice: choice,
    questionId: questionId,
    // feedback: should relationship go here?
  })
  answer.save()

controllers/feedback.js
newModel: null,
actions: {
  save(newModel) {
    newModel.save()
  }
}
```

So how the relationship should be assigned if feeback doesn't have an ID yet?

Also can I hold the answer saving till the newModel for feedback is saved? Actually, I tried to bubble getChoice action to parent controller but the same problem of null record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `feedback` controller in `feedback/question` and access `feedback` model and use it.

```
feedback: Ember.inject.controller('feedback')
```

and

```
  let answer = this.get('model.answer');
  let questionId = this.get('model.question').get('id');
  let feedback = this.get('feedback').get('model');

  answer.setProperties({
    choice,
    questionId,
    feedback 
  })
```

- Or to get the feedback record from feedback controller, you can use `this.modelFor('feedback')` in feedback/question route

```
routes/feedback/question.js
model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      question: this.get('store').findRecord('question', params.question_id),
      answer: this.get('store').createRecord('answer'),
      feedback: this.modelFor('feedback')
    })
  },
```

and

```
  let answer = this.get('model.answer');
  let questionId = this.get('model.question').get('id');
  let feedback = this.get('feedback');

  answer.setProperties({
    choice,
    questionId,
    feedback 
  })
```

Comment: Yes, answer is now aware of relationship to the feedback. But when saving the feedback it show answers as an empty array.

Comment: I have tried to pushObject to answers instead of saving but the error was : "Cannot read property 'modelName' of undefined".  
`feedback.get('answers').then((answers) => { answers.pushObject( answer.setProperties( ... ) ) })`

Comment: Before saving `feedback`, you can update `answer` record  to feedback record using pushObject. like `feedback.get('answers').pushObject(answer)`.. I haven't done this before. you can read https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/relationships/

Comment: I have updated your answer with saving to feedback. Now it is working!